# Scale image using imageresizing.net-ImageResizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am trying to integrate on one of the website to `imageresizer` and i am able to make it work but i am not sure about the security of this `ImageResizer` library  as on following page it show few basic commands for resizing images which can be passed as parameter as show on http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

My concern is that when we pass command variable as parameter in image path will it execute all commands like crop

example

Downsize image from `600x300` to `150x75` using following

```
< img  src="images/imageName.jpg?width=150">
```

Above line will resize image to `150x75` and quality is even good.

Now if i make change to above example and add `mode=crop`

```
 < img  src='images/imageName.jpg?width=150&mode=crop'>
```

will this actually crop my original image to `150x75`. Just want to clarify as i have implemented as

```
<httpModules>
  <!-- This is for IIS5, IIS6, and IIS7 Classic, and Cassini/VS Web Server-->
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: What are you asking? It's very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I am just starting to research this tool so I may be a little off base here, but I think you're asking if when you use this tool whether it crops the original image (meaning it overwrites the original with this newly cropped version). As I understand it, everything they do is in memory and does not modify the original file. Otherwise if you needed to go from `width=150` to `width=200`, you would lose that opportunity.